# Access redirect headers in http post request in AngularJs

Tags: json, angularjs, http-headers

Im just doing a simple post request.

Need to know can I can capture the redirect URL address from the success response.

[image: Gyazo]

and this how my response looks like.

I need that 'Location' property from the Response headers. How do you access it.

[image: Gyazo]

```js
$scope.doAltLogin = function(loginName) {
  //send POST req
  $http.post('/bin/ssga/altLoginServlet?method=doAltLogin&loginName=' + loginName)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //receive response
      //$window.location = data;
      conosle.log(headers()); //This shows everything except Location
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert('doAltLogin failed!');
    });

};
```

```html
<a ng-click="doAltLogin(user.loginName)" href="javascript:void(0)">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks guys.

I found a silly solution.

`<a ng-href="/bin/ssga/altLoginServlet?method=doAltLogin&loginName={{user.loginName}}">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</a>`

It works.

Answer (score 1):

All responses with **3xx** codes are served by a browser transparently to any AJAX call so it is not possible to access this response from your script.

As a workaround you could possibly serve redirects designed for AJAX calls with a different status code which your front end application would be aware of. Then you could serve such a response with a global interceptor.